# how to run two R codes in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to run two r codes in one .bat file. I have my codes setup as following, but I can only run 1 . What did I do wrong?

```
@echo off
START "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.5\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" D:\file\l_101.R /b

D:\file\l_102.R /b
```

Comment: Why are you only using `Rscript.exe` to run the first script and not the second one?

Comment: Is `/b` supposed to be an argument to `l_101.R` or an option for `START`.

Comment: @SomethingDark I thought I can call rscript once and run two r codes. Could I?

Comment: Certainly not like that, no. Also, was my question too difficult to answer?

Comment: @Compo As I am new to .bat, I am learning that from others' example and could not answer the question on /b . My guess it is for .R.

Comment: My guess is it's supposed to be for `START`, and as such should be used nearer to it, to prevent confusion. i.e. `START "" /b "%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.0.5\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "D:\file\l_101.R"`. Also that would have meant that the next line you wrote wouldn't use the `/b` option.

Comment: If the option `/b` is specified as written by Compo, it is interpreted by command __START__ of `cmd.exe`. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `start /?` and read the output help. If the option `/b` would be placed __between__ `"%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.0.5\bin\x64\Rscript.exe"` and `"D:\file\l_101.R"` it would be interpreted by `Rscript.exe`. If `/b` is specified after the R script file name `"D:\file\l_101.R"`, __START__ respectively `cmd.exe` passes the option to `Rscript.exe` which passes the option to script code inside `D:\file\l_101.R`.

Comment: Based on https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/Rscript, it indeed appears that `/b` is meant to be an argument for `start`, since R scripts take the `--arg` form instead of `/arg`.

Comment: @Mofi If I want rscript.exe to run both l_101.R and l_102.R , how should I write my .bat file?

Comment: That should be already clear. The first line is `start "" /b "%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.0.5\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "D:\file\l_101.R"` and the second line is `"%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.0.5\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "D:\file\l_102.R"`. If the two R scripts require as current directory `D:\file`, there should be used first in the batch file `cd /D "D:\file"` before starting twice `Rscript.exe` for interpreting the R scripts `l_101.R` and `l_102.R`. `cmd.exe` processing the batch file waits for self-termination of `Rscript.exe` interpreting `l_102.R` before it continues processing the batch file.

Comment: The first started `Rscript.exe` interpreting `l_101.R` is executed parallel to `cmd.exe` and second `Rscript.exe`. There can be used also just the two lines `start "l_101" /D "D:\file" "%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.0.5\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "D:\file\l_101.R"` and `start "l_102" /D "D:\file" "%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.0.5\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "D:\file\l_102.R"` which starts two instances of `Rscript.exe` each with its own console window with the window titles `l_101` and `l_102` executed both parallel to `cmd.exe` processing the batch file which immediately continues batch file processing.

Comment: `cmd.exe` closes itself on reaching end of the batch file while the two `Rscript.exe` processes are interpreting each one of the two R scripts. The execution of an executable without or with command `start` of `cmd.exe` determines how `cmd.exe` calls the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for execution of the executable. `cmd.exe` waits for self-termination of the started executable before it continues processing of the batch file on not using the command `start`.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks so much for such detailed explanation.  Learned a lot from you. 

Comment: @Moli When I excite .bat, I can see detailed program ran on the cmd screen. Is it possible to capture those as a log file. If it is do able, how? Many thanks.

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)). There can be inserted `(` at top of the batch file below `@echo off` to begin a command block and at end of the batch file `)>"%USERPROFILE%\%~n0.txt" 2>&1` to redirect all standard output and standard error into the text file with name of the batch file in your profile directory. The fully qualified file name can be of course any file name with a directory path of an already existing directory.